# Java Database Exceptional error that is very unique

Tags: java, database-connectivity

am getting the error shown from this code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeWqM.png)

```
private void formComponentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {                                    
    try{
        Connection conn = ConnectionProvider.getCon();
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs  = st.executeQuery("select max(pId) from product");
        if(rs.first()){
            int id = rs.getInt(1);
            id = id+1;
            String str = String.valueOf(id);
            jLabel4.setText(str);
        }
        else{
             jLabel4.setText("1");        
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
}
```

i wanted the code to change text on the label from 100 to whatever that was largest value  in an id column in product table of a database. the code was to increase that value after new data is entered and keep that as it's current value

Comment: Please post _error text_, not _pictures_ of error text, unless otherwise [relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/230513).

Comment: In addition to changing to `rs.next()` as has been recommended, you should really be using try-with-resources for your database objects

Comment: this is essentially unrelated to any ui (solve the backend problem before adding complexity of the ui, f.i. with simple printOuts). As to the ui: looks like swing, why did you tag javafx?

Answer (score 4):

Change `rs.first()` to `rs.next()`.  Your connection provider is returning a connection with a limitation that you can only read forward, and not randomly traverse the dataset.  Calling `rs.first()` is effectively asking to rewind to the first row, which is unnecessary since you're already poised to read forward to the first row.

Comment: Minor nitpick, but a result set is initially positioned *before* the first row (which is why you must position it with `next()` before doing anything).

Comment: Minor nitpick corrected.